# How can I convert a state name to it's abbreviation?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a search term handler function to search facilities by state or zip.

```
  searchTermHandler(event) {
    this.presentLoading();
    let searchTerm = event.detail.value;
    this.stateList.forEach((state) => {
      if (state.abbreviation.toLowerCase == searchTerm.toLowerCase) {
        console.log("A state.");
        this.dataService.getFacilitiesByState(searchTerm);
      } else if (state.name.toLowerCase == searchTerm.toLowerCase) {
        // @TODO: Convert state name to abbreviation, then send abbrev. to get facility by state.
        this.dataService.getFacilitiesByState(searchTerm);
      } else if (parseInt(searchTerm) != NaN) {
        if (searchTerm.length != 5) {
          alert("Please enter a 5 digit zip code.");
          console.log("A number, but not 5 digits.");
        } else {
          this.dataService.getFacilitiesByZip(searchTerm);
          console.log("A 5 digit number.");
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

And I also have a json file with states and their abbreviations. Here's a sample...

```
     "stateList": [
    {
        "name": "Alabama",
        "abbreviation": "AL"
    },
    {
        "name": "Alaska",
        "abbreviation": "AK"
    },
    {
        "name": "American Samoa",
        "abbreviation": "AS"
    },
    {
        "name": "Arizona",
        "abbreviation": "AZ"
    },
    {
        "name": "Arkansas",
        "abbreviation": "AR"
    },
    {
        "name": "California",
        "abbreviation": "CA"
    },
    {
        "name": "Colorado",
        "abbreviation": "CO"
    }
]
```

How can I convert a state name to it's abbreviation? So that I can send that to another function that searches for facilities by state with abbreviations.

Thank you!

Comment: You need to call the function: `toLowerCase()`.

Comment: The check for zip code shouldn't be in the `forEach()` loop, since it's not dependent on the state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking for a ZIP code should not be inside the loop, since it's not dependent on the states that you're looping over. Do that before searching for the state abbreviations.

Use the `.find()` method to find the matching state object, then extract the abbreviation from that.

```
searchTermHandler(event) {
    this.presentLoading();
    let searchTerm = event.detail.value;
    if (parseInt(searchTerm) != NaN) {
        if (searchTerm.length != 5) {
            alert("Please enter a 5 digit zip code.");
            console.log("A number, but not 5 digits.");
        } else {
            this.dataService.getFacilitiesByZip(searchTerm);
            console.log("A 5 digit number.");
        }
    } else {
        let searchLower = searchTerm.toLowerCase();
        let state = this.stateList.find((state) => state.abbreviation.toLowerCase() == searchLower || state.name.toLowerCase() == searchLower);
        if (state) {
            console.log("State abbreviation is: " + state.abbreviation);
            this.dataService.getFacilitiesByState(state.abbreviation);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Let's refactor the code later. How can I convert a state name to it's abbreviation?

Comment: That's what everything below `let searchLower` does. `state.abbreviation` is the abbreviation of the state that the user entered.